# Fill in missing dates for a pandas dataframe with multiple series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains multiple time series, like so:

| Date | Item | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | gouda | cheese |
| 2021-01-02 | gouda | cheese |
| 2021-01-04 | gouda | cheese |
| 2021-01-05 | gouda | cheese |
| 2021-02-01 | lettuce | produce |
| 2021-02-02 | lettuce | produce |
| 2021-02-03 | lettuce | produce |
| 2021-02-05 | lettuce | produce |

I'd like to add rows for the missing dates (ex. 2021-01-03 for gouda, 2021-02-04 for lettuce). **Note that these series do not necessarily start and end on the same date.**

What is the best way to do this in pandas? I'd also like fill the new rows with the values in the "item" and "category" column for that series.

Comment: I would suggest looping through the Date column with some logic to find missing dates and then inserting a row when you find a missing one. This would look something like a for loop through each row[0] and if the previous day is not 1 day behind the current day then insert a row at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by `Item` and `Category`, then generate a time series from the min to the max date:

```py
result = (
    df.groupby(["Item", "Category"])["Date"]
    .apply(lambda s: pd.date_range(s.min(), s.max()))
    .explode()
    .reset_index()
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do `resample`

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Y-m'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%y-%m')
out = df.groupby('Y-m').apply(lambda x : x.set_index('Date').resample('D').ffill()).reset_index(level=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is far from optimal, but it is how I would do in order to ensure all categories and items are within the min and max periods, and all ranges are filled:

```
aux = []
for x in df['Item'].unique():
  _ = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(df[df['Item']==x]['Date'].min(),df[df['Item']==x]['Date'].max(),freq='d')})
  _['Item'] = x
  _['Category'] = df[df['Item']==x]['Category'].values[0]
  aux.append(_)
output = pd.concat(aux)
```

Consider this sample dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2021-01-01','2021-01-02','2021-01-04','2021-01-05','2021-01-01','2021-01-02','2021-01-04','2021-01-05'],
                   'Item':['gouda','gouda','gouda','gouda','lettuce','lettuce','lettuce','lettuce'],
                   'Category':['cheese','cheese','cheese','cheese','produce','produce','produce','produce']})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Outputs:

```
        Date     Item Category
0 2021-01-01    gouda   cheese
1 2021-01-02    gouda   cheese
2 2021-01-03    gouda   cheese
3 2021-01-04    gouda   cheese
4 2021-01-05    gouda   cheese
0 2021-01-01  lettuce  produce
1 2021-01-02  lettuce  produce
2 2021-01-03  lettuce  produce
3 2021-01-04  lettuce  produce
4 2021-01-05  lettuce  produce
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to explicitly generate missing rows:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.complete(
    {'Date': lambda date: pd.date_range(date.min(), date.max())}, 
    by = ['Item', 'Category'], 
    sort = True)
 
        Date     Item Category
0 2021-01-01    gouda   cheese
1 2021-01-02    gouda   cheese
2 2021-01-03    gouda   cheese
3 2021-01-04    gouda   cheese
4 2021-01-05    gouda   cheese
5 2021-02-01  lettuce  produce
6 2021-02-02  lettuce  produce
7 2021-02-03  lettuce  produce
8 2021-02-04  lettuce  produce
9 2021-02-05  lettuce  produce
```

The dictionary helps introduce values into the dataframe. The key of the dataframe should be an existing column; the lambda function refers to the `Date` column